# javafx custom component issue

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls

I want load my custom component in my fxml file directly. But I have an error when I run my example.

MyFXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import br.com.prati.collaboration.iem.components.PratiLabel?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon?>
<?import br.com.prati.collaboration.iem.components.FillEmoticon?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="br.prati.tim.collaboration.iem.view.MetasDisplay" style="-fx-background-color: white;" prefWidth="800" prefHeight="600">
  <padding>
    <Insets top="8" left="5" right="5" />
  </padding>
  <GridPane>
    <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" minHeight="10" />
      <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" minHeight="10" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
      <PratiLabel title="Lote Programado" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
      <PratiLabel title="Lote Realizado" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
      <PratiLabel fx:id="statusPane" title="Status Lote" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="2" alignment="CENTER">
        <nodes>
          <FillEmoticon sizeEM="10" fill="YELLOW" />
        </nodes>
      </PratiLabel>
    </children>
  </GridPane>
</VBox>
```

snippet fxml with my custom component FillEmoticon

```
...
<nodes>
  <FillEmoticon sizeEM="10" fill="YELLOW"/>
</nodes>
```

class

```
package br.com.prati.collaboration.iem.components;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsBuilder;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcons;

public class FillEmoticon extends StackPane {

    private static final double SCALE_EM_TO_PX = 4.5;

    private GlyphIcon<?> icon;
    private Circle filled;

    private double sizeEM = 4.5;

    public FillEmoticon() {


        String iconStyle = "-fx-font-size: 4em; -fx-fill: black; -fx-stroke-width: 2px;";

        icon = GlyphsBuilder.create(FontAwesomeIcon.class)
                .glyph(FontAwesomeIcons.SMILE_ALT)
                .style(iconStyle)
                .build();

        filled = new Circle( 4 * sizeEM, Paint.valueOf("GREEN"));

        getChildren().addAll(filled, icon);

    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.icon.setGlyphName(name);
    }

    public void setFill(String paint){
        filled.setFill(Paint.valueOf(paint));
    }

    public String getFill(String paint){
        return filled.getFill().toString();
    }

    public void setSizeEM(double value){
        icon.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + value + "em; -fx-font-family: Fontawesome;");
        filled.setRadius(value * SCALE_EM_TO_PX);
    }

    public double getSizeEM(){
        return sizeEM;
    }

}
```

error when I run

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1463801669.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/externo/Iem/inspecao.embalagem-jar/target/classes/fxml/Metas.fxml:37

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2583)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at br.prati.tim.collaboration.iem.view.MetasDisplay.start(MetasDisplay.java:30)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/606827964.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1681433494.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1144405258.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1685538367.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2058534881.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "fill" does not exist or is read-only.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:344)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:321)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:231)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:763)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2827)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2536)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application br.prati.tim.collaboration.iem.view.MetasDisplay
```

Whats is the problem with my custom component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it seems you need to structure it like this:

```
public class FillEmoticon {

    public StringProperty fill = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty fillProperty() {
        return fill ;
    }

    public final String getFill() {
        return fillProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFill(String fill) {
        fillProperty().set(fill);
    }

    public FillEmoticon() {
        // ...
        fill.addListener((obs, oldFill, newFill) -> filled.setFill(Paint.valueOf(newFill)));

    }

    // ...
}
```

and then in the FXML you have to use a property element, instead of an attribute:

```
<FillEmoticon>
    <fill>YELLOW</fill>
</FillEmoticon>
```

Note that since `Paint` has a `valueOf` method, you can access it directly, instead of indirectly through a `String`. This makes things a bit easier:

```
public class FillEmoticon {

    // code exactly as you have, except for get/setFill

    public ObjectProperty<Paint> fillProperty() {
        return filled.fillProperty();
    }

    public final void setFill(Paint fill) {
        fillProperty().set(fill);
    }

    public final Paint getFill() {
        return fillProperty().get();
    }

}
```

and then your current FXML seems to work.